# Average of ratios compared to ratio of averages

Tags: statistics, intuition, average, ratio

How to formalize (in simple terms) when average of ratios would be  greater than ratio of averages?
I found that sometimes the former is greater than the latter and sometimes the latter is greater than the former.
I want to understand in what cases one would be greater than the other.

What happens at asymptotic?
And what happens in day to day calculations? Which should I expect to be greater?

Comment: You are trying to compare $\frac{\frac ab +\frac cd}{2}$ and $\frac{\frac {a+c}{2}}{\frac {b+d}{2}}$ with a difference of $\frac{(b-d)(bc-ad)}{2bd(b+d)}$ and the sign of the difference depends on the sign of the numerator

Comment: Do you mean with two arbitrary datasets? Are there any assumptions on independence or lack of it? For datasets, $\overline x/\overline y$ vs $\overline{\left(x/y\right)}$ can have any relationship due to random variation. Though, there will be a set relationship between the expectations $E(X/Y)$ vs $E(X)/E(Y)$, but this can go either way depending on the underlying distributions.

Answer (score 3):

Let us start the conversation with just 4 numbers for simplicity.

Note that neither the Average of Ratios
$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}}2 \tag{AR}$$
nor the Ratio of Averages
$$\frac{\frac{a+c}2}{\frac{b+d}2}=\frac{a+c}{b+d} \tag{RA}$$
change when all 4 numbers are scaled together, to the relationship between AR and RA depends only on the *projective* point $a:b:c:d$.

Now, let us scale $(a,b)$ to $(\lambda a,\lambda b)$, then AR does not change and RA goes from $\frac{a}{b}$ for $\lambda=\infty$ to $\frac{c}{d}$ for $\lambda=0$.

This should give you *intuition* you are asking for:
*ratio of averages* is the *average of ratios* ***weighted*** by their *denominators*:
$$ \frac{a+c}{b+d} = \frac{b}{b+d}\times\frac{a}{b} + \frac{d}{b+d}\times\frac{c}{d}$$
while AR is their average with weights $\frac12$, and this generalizes directly to an arbitrary number of ratios.

Thus AR will be **bigger** when the **bigger** ratio has a **bigger** denominator.

Related:

- [Simple question regarding ratio and average](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80583/37092)
- [Ratio of Averages vs Average of Ratios](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2762574/37092)

Answer (score 0):

Too long as a comment:

---

> average of ratios

1. Does the “average of $3{:}4$ and $5{:}6$” mean $4{:}5$ or $19{:}24$ ?
2. What does the “average of $3{:}5{:}7$ and $1{:}2{:}3$” mean?

Given three fractions $\dfrac{x_1}{k_1},\dfrac{x_2}{k_2},\dfrac{x_3}{k_3},$

- their **arithmetic mean** is $$\boxed{\frac13\left(\dfrac{x_1}{k_1}+\dfrac{x_2}{k_2}+\frac{x_3}{k_3}\right)}=\frac{x_1k_2k_3+k_1x_2k_3+k_1k_2x_3}{3\:k_1 k_2 k_3}.$$

This is what you mean by “average of ratios”.

> ratio of averages

When they are assigned weights according to their denominators, then

- their **weighted arithmetic mean** is $$\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2+k_3}\left(\dfrac{x_1}{k_1}\right)+\frac{k_2}{k_1+k_2+k_3}\left(\dfrac{x_2}{k_2}\right)+\frac{k_3}{k_1+k_2+k_3}\left(\frac{x_3}{k_3}\right)\\=\boxed{\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{k_1+k_2+k_3}}\\=\frac{\frac13\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)}{\frac13\left(k_1+k_2+k_3\right)}.$$

This is what you mean by “ratio of averages”.

Comment: This an explanation but it doesn't adress the question and doesn't answer it

Comment: My opening sentence means that the points I was making are collectively too much to be posted in the comment box (the usual way). P.S. I just edited my first line for typos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Chebyshev inequality for sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) to conclude:

$x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n$ and $\frac{y_1}{x_1}\le \frac{y_2}{x_2} \le \cdots \frac{y_n}{x_n}$ then

$$
\frac{\sum \lambda_i \frac{y_i}{x_i}}{\sum \lambda_i} \le \frac{\sum \lambda_i y_i}{\sum \lambda_i x_i}$$

If the ratios and the denominators are in reversed orders then the inequality is reversed.

Note that $\lambda_i$ are some positive weights, they could be $\frac{1}{n}$ if one takes equal weights. Now the standard Chebyshev inequality does not require the other numbers to be positive, but here we do a division, so we'd better have $\sum \lambda_i x_i >0$.